# How do you delete rows that match in two separate tables using SQL?

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms

In SQL coding using SQL Server Management Studio I am able to delete from tables which have different row counts when inserting or deleting. AFTER I update table A, I would like to delete matching items from table A if the are in table B. The idea is to end up with only the rows which have been updated in table A. I have 10 columns but will use 4 to keep it simple.

```
CREATE TRIGGER utr_Updates
ON  tableA
AFTER UPDATE
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    EXEC usp_updates
END

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_Updates
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tableA 
               WHERE col1 IN (SELECT DISTINCT col1 FROM tableB))
        DELETE FROM tableA 
        WHERE col1 IN (SELECT DISTINCT col1 FROM tableB)

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tableA 
               WHERE col2 IN (SELECT DISTINCT col2 FROM tableB))
        DELETE FROM tableA 
        WHERE col2 IN (SELECT DISTINCT col2 FROM tableB)

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tableA 
               WHERE col3 IN (SELECT DISTINCT col3 FROM tableB))
        DELETE FROM tableA 
        WHERE col3 IN (SELECT DISTINCT col3 FROM tableB)

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tableA 
               WHERE col4 IN (SELECT DISTINCT col4 FROM tableB))
        DELETE FROM tableA 
        WHERE col4 IN (SELECT DISTINCT col4 FROM tableB)
END
```

START POINT

```
                  START

    TABLE A                TABLE B
col1 W, X, Y, Z         col1 W, X, Y, Z
col2 1, 2, 3, 4         col2 1, 2, 3, 4
col3 A, 5, 6, D         col3 A, 5, 6, D
col4 7, B, C, D         col3 7, B, C, D
```

TABLE A UPDATED AT col1 and col3

```
               AFTER UPDATE

    TABLE A                TABLE B
col1 W, S, Y, Z         col1 W, X, Y, Z
col2 1, 2, 3, 4         col2 1, 2, 3, 4
col3 A, 5, 1, D         col3 A, 5, 6, D
col4 7, B, C, D         col3 7, B, C, D
```

DESIRED RESULT

```
     TABLE A   
 col1 W, S, Y, Z
 col3 A, 5, 1, D
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select a.*
from a
where not exists (select 1
                  from b
                  where b.col1 = a.col1 and b.col2 = a.col2 and b.col3 = a.col3 and b.col4 = a.col4
                 );
```

Or, in SQL Server, you can use `EXCEPT`:

```
select a.*
from a
except
select b.*
from b;
```